# error: invalid suffix "i64" on integer constant

Tags: c++, compilation

When compiling tor I get the following error in torint.h...

```
src\tor\torint.h:190: error: invalid suffix "i64" on integer constant
 #define INT64_MAX 0x7fffffffffffffffi64
               ^
```

specifically on the line below.

https://github.com/arlolra/tor/blob/master/src/common/torint.h#L190

The code linked above is the second line in the code below...

```
#ifndef INT64_MAX
#define INT64_MAX 0x7fffffffffffffffi64
#endif
```

I am building on Windows 7 64-bit with MingW32 using gcc 4.8.2. The full output for gcc -v is below. I have read that this could be an environment problem but am unable to find a solution. Any advice on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/lto-wra
pper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-4.8.2/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --buil
d=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw32 --with-sysroot=/c
/mingw482/i686-482-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-r2/mingw32 --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw32/
i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++ --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib
--enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=ye
s --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enabl
e-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runti
me-libs --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-isl-version-check --di
sable-cloog-version-check --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --en
able-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-
werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=i686 --with-tun
e=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw482/prerequisite
s/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw482/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32
-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw482/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=
/c/mingw482/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-cloog=/c/mingw482/prere
quisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-pkgversion='i
686-posix-dwarf, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.ne
t/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/mingw482/i686-482-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-
r2/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw482/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c
/mingw482/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/
c/mingw482/i686-482-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-r2/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw482/prere
quisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw482/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-s
tatic/include' CPPFLAGS= LDFLAGS='-pipe -L/c/mingw482/i686-482-posix-dwarf-rt_v3
-r2/mingw32/opt/lib -L/c/mingw482/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw4
82/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/lib -Wl,--large-address-aware'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (i686-posix-dwarf, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

Comment: [This should help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835746/how-do-you-specify-a-64-bit-unsigned-int-const-0x8000000000000000-in-vs2008), i64 is a microsoft thing only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i64` is not a standard integer literal suffix, so this must be a compiler extension. The draft C++ standard in section `2.14.2` *Integer literals* defines the following integer literal suffixes:

```
integer-suffix:
    unsigned-suffix long-suffixopt
    unsigned-suffix long-long-suffixopt
    long-suffix unsigned-suffixopt
    long-long-suffix unsigned-suffixopt
unsigned-suffix: one of
    u U
long-suffix: one of
    l L
long-long-suffix: one of
    ll LL
```

we can see that Microsoft does allow such a suffix in C++ from their [C++ Integer Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00a1awxf.aspx) page.

The correct suffix for `gcc` should be `ll` based on the source you linked to but this requires SIZEOF_LONG_LONG == 8.

As Keith points out using the `LL` suffix is probably better than using `ll` since it is equivalent and `ll` it could easily be mistaken for `11`(*one one*) or even mis-typed.

Comment: `LL` is also valid and much better (`ll` is too easy to mistake for `11`).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a misconfiguration.

`i64` is a Microsoft-specific suffix, and the branch defining `INT64_MAX` this way is triggered when `SIZEOF___INT64 == 8`, and that in turn can happen only if `src/win32/orconfig.h` is included.

Comment: Not only does it require `SIZEOF___INT64 == 8`, it also requires `SIZEOF_LONG_LONG != 8`. GCC has supported `long long` for a `long long` time (sorry), so a properly generated config header for GCC would have no problems.

Comment: @hvd and `orconfig.h` undefines `SIZEOF_LONG_LONG` as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
#ifndef INT64_MAX
#define INT64_MAX 0x7fffffffffffffffLL
#endif
```