# C - BitArray - Set single bit of uint64_t

Tags: c, casting, bit-shift, memory-efficient, bitarray

I'm currently working on a project, in which I need bit sets. I'm using an array of `uint64_t`'s for the bitset.

My current problem is, that whenever I want to set or check a bit I need to do an operation like this:

```
uint64_t index = 42;
bArr[index/64] |= (((uint64_t)1)<<(index%64));
```

I can rewrite the division and modulo with some clever *and* and *bitshift* operations as well, but I'm concerned about the cast of `1`. I need this cast, since otherwise the `1` is seen as a 32-bit unit. As seen in this example - you get wrong output without a cast:

```
uint64_t bArr[4];                           // 256 bits 
bArr[0] = bArr[1] = bArr[2] = bArr[3] = 0;  // Set to 0

uint64_t i = 255;
bArr[i/64] = (bArr[i/64] | (((uint64_t)1)<<(i%64))); 

uint32_t i2;
for (i2 = 0; i2 < 256; i2++) {
  if ((bArr[i2/64] & (((uint64_t)1)<<(i2%64))) != 0) {
    printf("bArray[%" PRIu32 "] = 1\n", i2);
  }
}
```

Can I get around this cast in a clever way? I was thinking that the performance is probably suffering from a cast at *every* read/write...

Comment: Do *not* rewrite the division and modulo to be "clever"; the compiler is certainly clever enough to already do those optimizations for you. Also consider using `CHAR_BIT * sizeof bArr[0]` instead of `64`, to avoid magic numbers.

Comment: @unwind Thanks for the tip. I'll test it with my code. This is probably the case though.

Comment: If you're looking for speed, provide a `const uint64_t` table with the 64 different ULL constants (1 pre-shifted into all possible places) and index into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result type of `<<` operator is the type of the left operand (after integer promotions) that's why you need to use the correct type: `1` is of type `int` but you need type `uint64_t`.

You can use either:

```
(uint64_t) 1
```

or

```
UINT64_C(1)  /* you have to include <stdint.h> */
```

or

```
1ULL
```

(for the last one assuming `unsigned long long` is 64-bit in your system which is very likely).

But they are all equivalent: all these expressions are integer constant expressions and their value is computed at compile time and not at run time.

Comment: Great to know, that this happens at compile time and won't affect performance (only uglifies the code)...

Comment: Detail `unsigned long long` is at least 64-bit, so `bArr[index/64] |= 1ULL <<(index%64);` will certainly work.  Assuming `unsigned long long` is 64-bit is not needed.

Comment: @chux Will it break when `unsigned long long` is greater than 64-bit? I'm not exactly sure what is happening. Could you try to explain, what happens without a cast? I saw the wrong output and was assuming it had to do something with the width (and therefore successfully tried the cast). I would like to know, why the code broke ...

Comment: @chux you are right, it was actually to make the point in my last sentence that three expressions are equivalent (but for this I should also mention `uint_least64_t` can be different than `unsigned long long`).

Comment: @Matthias it will work the same if `unsigned long long` width is greater than 64-bit.

Comment: The only down-side to using `1ULL` vs. `UINT64_C(1)` I see, in a more complex expression, is that `1ULL`  may go  to a wider type than `uint64_t` and create issues like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19453213/2410359).  Certainly rare in 2016 as `unsigned long long` is commonly 64-bit.

Comment: @chux nice example. When dealing with `uint64_t` objects for example, I would prefer `(uint64_t) 1` so I'm sure the computations will be done using the exact same type.

Comment: Agreed.  For robust code I prefer `((uint64_t)1)` over `1ULL` to insure the desired type too.  Yet with simple `bArr[index/64] |= 1ull <<(index%64);`, Using `ULL` is appealing.  `INT64_C(1)` is best for portability as `uint64_t` need not exist, yet `int_leastN_t` will.  But that `uint64_t` is assumed to exist in OP's example.

Answer (score 3):

A cast in and of itself does not affect performance.  It's a compile time construct that tells the compiler the type of an expression.

In this case, they're all integer casts and expressions, so there should be no performance impact.

Comment: Oh, you again :) So as you'll probably remember this is pretty much your code (only with `uint64_t`). Also do you know what size is probably the best to use for the array `uint64_t`, `uint32_t`, `uint16_t` or even `uint8_t`? I'm having L1/L2 cache size in my mind, but don't know much about it...

Comment: *a cast [...] is a compile time construct that tells the compiler the type of an expression*  it's not correct to say a cast is a compile time construct when in most cases it's not.

Answer (score 3):

C offer macros for this which will expand the integer constant to the type `int_leastN_t`.

```
INTN_C(value)
UINTN_C(value)
```

Example

```
#include <stdint.h>.
bArr[index/64] |= UINT64_C(1) << (index%64);
```

In *general* it is better to avoid casting.  Sometimes casting unexpectedly make the expression *narrower* than hoped.

---

Benefit of `UINT64_C`: `uint_least_64_t/int_least_64_t` types must exist (C99).  `int64_t/uint64_t` are optional.

Comment: Nice macro, thanks for the tip :) In this case casting should be fine, since I always working on `uin64_t` right?

Comment: Is there any benefit in choosing `INT64_C` over a cast to `(int64_t)`?

Comment: @a3f  Answer edited to address a benefit.  When N is >= `unsigned/int` width and `(u)intN_t` exist, certainly `INTN_C()` and casting `(intN_t)` behave alike.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want a literal 1 that is at least 64 bits long. You can [get this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835746/how-do-you-specify-a-64-bit-unsigned-int-const-0x8000000000000000-in-vs2008) without any casts by writing `1ull` instead of just `1`. This creates an `unsigned long long` literal with the value 1. However, the type is not guaranteed not to be longer than 64-bits, so if you rely on it being exactly 64-bits you may need a cast after all.